# Oracle query - can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone tell me why the following query is considered invalid in Oracle?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(start_date,'dd/month')
FROM Table1
WHERE start_date IN (TO_DATE('JUN 15 12'), TO_DATE('AUG 19 12'));
```

Is it because 'dd/month' is considered invalid format when combined?

or is it because date cannot be compared using IN?

P.S> I do not have access to Oracle database at this time that's why i can't run the sql and get exact error. All I know is the statement is invalid and I wanted to know what is the problem. I am new to Oracle

Comment: I guess you have 2 errors: in `to_char` and in `to_date`. Both seem invalid to me since they are either using invalid pattern or missing it at all.

Comment: You can run your SQL here: http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @ElenaDBA: No, you can choose from MySQL (5.5 and 5.6), Oracle (11g), SQL-Server (2008 or 2012), SQLite, Postgres (several versions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have changed your session/database parameters, TO_DATE format should be in form dd-mon-yy. The second parameter to TO_DATE is the incoming date format.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(start_date,'DD/MONTH')
FROM Table1
WHERE start_date IN (TO_DATE('JUN 15 2012', 'MON DD YYYY'), TO_DATE('AUG 19 2012', 'MON DD YYYY'));
```

Comment: sorry, my bad, it should have been                              WHERE start_date IN (TO_DATE('JUN 15 12'), TO_DATE('AUG 19 12'));

Comment: Doesn't matter. Unless your default date format (by session or system configuration) is 'MON DD YY' then you will need to provide a format to the to_date calls

Comment: It is just good practice anyway to not assume a date format configuration parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try supplying the format in `TO_DATE` method as below:

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(start_date,'DD/Month')
 FROM Table1
 WHERE start_date IN (
         to_date('JUN 15 2012', 'MON DD YYYY'), 
         to_date('AUG 19 2012', 'MON DD YYYY')
 );
```

Also if you want to use `BETWEEN` to find all records falling in the date range then:

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(start_date,'DD/Month')
 FROM Table1
 WHERE start_date BETWEEN to_date('JUN 15 2012', 'MON DD YYYY')
                      AND to_date('AUG 19 2012', 'MON DD YYYY');
```